# What would be the most logical way of putting multiple radial gradients on one HTML element

Tags: html, css, radial-gradients

For a client I am trying to implement a background on an HTML element, which contains 2 radial gradients. One is located in the top right, one is located in the bottom left. My CSS only renders one of the radial gradients.

I have tried putting two radial gradient elements as a background:

```css
body {
            width: 100vw;
            height: 100vh;
            background-color: green;
            background:
                radial-gradient(
                    circle at top right,
                    red,
                    black 20%

                ),
                radial-gradient(
                    circle at bottom left,
                    yellow,
                    orange 20%
                );
        }
```

Only the first radial-gradient appears, but the second one doesn't. When I switch the position of both gradients in de CSS markup, the colors change. So it appears as if only the first gradient is recognised.

Comment: Cool, this seems to work and it renders two radial gradients. The only side effect that occurs now is that the background-color of green would disappear. A white (transparent) background now appears in between the two gradients, instead of the desired green background. What would be the most appropriate way of getting the green background back? Thanks in advance!

Comment: OK, I posted an answer. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure which amount of color you want to see in the result, but my guess is you are after something like this.

```css
body {
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    margin:0;
    background-color: green;
    background-image:
        radial-gradient(
            circle at top right,
            red,
            black 20%,
            transparent 40%

        ),
        radial-gradient(
            circle at bottom left,
            yellow,
            orange 20%,
            transparent 40%
        );
}
```

One problem with your code was that you used the `background` shorthand for the background images, which resets the background color,  so the green was no longer there. Use `background-image` instead.
Another was that both gradients covered the whole page, while you apparently want them to take up only the top right corner and bottom left corner instead. I solved this by giving them both `transparent` from 40%.
And I took the liberty of giving the body `0` margin, to get rid of the scrollbars.

Answer (score 2):

> My CSS only renders one of the radial gradients.

Simply because you are using opaque colors and by default a gradient will cover all the element so your will only see the top layer.

In addition to the answer of Mr Lister, you can adjust `background-size` to control the space each gradient should take:

```css
body {
  margin:0;
  height: 100vh;
  background: 
    radial-gradient(circle at top right, red, black 40%) right, 
    radial-gradient(circle at bottom left, yellow, orange 40%) left;
  background-size:50% 100%;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

This looks a bit ugly but if you want to have a continuous background make sure both end color are the same:

```css
body {
  margin:0;
  height: 100vh;
  background: 
    radial-gradient(circle at top right  , red,    black  40%, green 60%) right, 
    radial-gradient(circle at bottom left, yellow, orange 40%, green 60%) left;
  background-size:50.5% 100%;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```